# How to vectorize outer product of column vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, algorithms

Suppose I have a matrix $X \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$
$$
X=
\begin{pmatrix}
{\bf{x}}_1^\top \\
\vdots\\
{\bf{x}}_n^\top
\end{pmatrix}
$$
made of $n$ column vectors ${\bf{x}}_i\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times 1}$. Suppose also I have another vector ${\bf{y}}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ and I want to compute
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n y_i {\bf{x}}_i {\bf{x}}_i^\top
$$
How can I "vectorize" this?

I thought about somehow creating a matrix containing all the outer products and then multiplying this matrix by ${\bf{y}}$ and then summing up the elements. But I'm not sure how to go about it.

## My Working

So far I realized the following:
$$
X^\top X = 
\begin{pmatrix}
{\bf{x}}_1, \ldots, {\bf{x}}_n\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
{\bf{x}}_1^\top \\
\vdots\\
{\bf{x}}_n^\top
\end{pmatrix} = {\bf{x}}_1{\bf{x}}_1^\top + \ldots +{\bf{x}}_n{\bf{x}}_n^\top = \sum_{i=1}^n {\bf{x}}_i{\bf{x}}_i^\top
$$

## Extra Working

I also just realized this.

$$
{\bf{y}}^\top X =
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 & \cdots & y_n
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
{\bf{x}}_1^\top \\
\vdots \\
{\bf{x}}_n^\top
\end{pmatrix} = y_1{\bf{x}}_1^\top + \cdots + y_n{\bf{x}}_n^\top
$$

Comment: maybe $X^\top X$ could be useful?

Comment: The formula you got is the best you're going to get unless you are interested in speeding up matrix-vector products

Comment: @whpowell96 Well I'm implementing this as part of a Newton-Raphson algorithm (basically this calculation happens to find the Hessian). I'm interested in **any** speeding up. How do you think I could speed this up? What do you mean?

Comment: You can write
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n y_i {\bf{x}}_i {\bf{x}}_i^\top = X^T \operatorname{diag}(y) X.
$$
where $ \operatorname{diag}(y)$ is the diagonal matrix whose entries on the diagonal are $y$. This is not usually what the term "vectorize" refers to, but perhaps this is the kind of thing you're looking for

Comment: Also, your equation involving $y^TX$ is incorrect

Comment: To compute the matrix-vector product with a vector $v$, the fastest way would probably by to compute $Xv$, then copmonent-wise multiply by the elements of $y$, then multiply that result by $X^T$. This can be used by a method like GMRES or maybe conjugate gradient to perform the linear solves at each Newton iteration.

Unless you meant Jacobian instead of Hessian, you are using Newton's Method for optimization. This can result in a lot of problems with convergence depending on your problem and something like BFGS might be a better choice depending on what software you are using

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Does this edit fixes the typo? Since ${\bf{y}}$ is $n\times 1$ and $X$ is $n\times p$ then ${\bf{y}}^\top X$ should be $1\times p$ right?

Comment: The edit makes sense, but now your latter expression involving $\tilde y$ doesn't make sense

Comment: @Omnomnomnom true. Thank you for the tip! If you post an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n y_i {\bf{x}}_i {\bf{x}}_i^\top = X^T \operatorname{diag}(y) X.
$$
where $\operatorname{diag}(y)$ is the diagonal matrix whose entries on the diagonal are $y$.

Comment: @R A row, as in the question

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo ${\bf{x}}_i$ is a column vector, meaning that it has dimension $p \times 1$. However, each ${\bf{x}}_i$, when transposed is a row of the matrix $X$.